# how to run a gulp task after angular-cli@webpack finishes bundling?

Tags: angular, gulp, webpack, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli@webpack.

I have configured my node services using gulp and to run my json-server I am executing my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var server = require('gulp-express');
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var typescript=require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var del = require('del');
var tsconfig = typescript.createProject('src/tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('default',function(){
    // Start the server at the beginning of the task 
    console.log('Start the server at the beginning of the task');
    server.run(['server/json-server-starter.js']);
});
```

Now for running my angular2 project I am using `npm start` .

I want to have a functionality that after angular-cli completes bundling of my app , json-server should be started.

I have tried including below command in package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve && gulp",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
}
```

But it doesnt run the gulpfile after bundling the app.
If I include `gulp` before `ng serve` then only `gulpfile` runs, webpack doesnt run the angular2 application.

So is there any way I can run both tasks simultaneously?

any inputs?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `(ng serve &) && gulp`.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Tried this, no success

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found one solution for this on windows.

it states that using below command in `package.json` can run both gulp & webpack simultaneously:

```
"start": "start ng serve && start gulp"
```

Thanks for the response.